# ffmpeg async io?

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

Anyone know if ffmpeg does asynchronous file io? That is, the input file is read in a separate thread as to avoid io blocking the processing thread?

Basically what I want to figure out is whether or not i need to do calls to "av_read_frame" inside a separate thread (to avoid blocking) or if ffmpeg alrdy handles this issue?

How might I figure this out? I've tried downloading the ffmpeg source but haven't been able to find anything useful.

Comment: Considering the function signature only, I can't see how it could be anything but blocking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it yourself. FFmpeg only has minimal thread awareness, and as icecrime said, the function signature obviously precludes doing it asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

While I am still only an ffmpeg novice, it is my understanding that the specific function you mention is NOT threaded by the ffmpeg api.  You will probably want to thread this anyway because you will need to decide what type of frame is returned (audio, video, etc...) and then decide what to do with it.